# В чем отличие методов

Tags: c++

Не могли бы вы мне подсказать в чем разница между:

```
template <typename Key>
class SelfMap {

    const Proxy operator[] (Key key)
    {
        return Proxy(*this, key);
    }

    //и 
    //@VladD исправил
    Proxy* operator[] (Key key)
    {
        Proxy *p =new Proxy(*this, key);
        return p;
    }

    //или же 
    const Proxy operator[] (Key key)
    {
        Proxy p(*this, key);
        return p;
    }

};
```

Если уточнить, мне интересно:

1) При `return Proxy(*this, key);` как происходит уничтожение объекта и при каких условиях? Возможно ли что я его потеряю, и он засорит память?

2) При `return p;` как тут уничтожается объект и уничтожается ли?

3) При указателе, можно ли самому уничтожить объект?

Цель данных экспериментов у меня была, выяснить, можно ли при одинаковых ключах вызывать один и тот же прокси класс. И как это сделать если ключей будет много.

Буду очень рад примеру и/или объяснению.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `return Proxy(*this, key);`

   Создаётся новый объект №1 на стеке, и возвращается как результат. Объект копируется в принимающую переменную (таким образом, там создаётся ещё один объект №2) при помощи конструктора копирования. Объект №1 уничтожается.
2. `Proxy *p=Proxy(*this, key); return p;`

   Создаётся новый объект в куче, указатель на него возвращается из функции. Объект не умрёт сам, пока вы его не «уничтожите» вручную.

   Объявление функции

   ```
   Proxy operator[] (Key key)
   ```

   в этом случае не покатит, т. к. у `p` тип `Proxy*`, а не `Proxy`.
3. Если у вас есть указатель на объект, выделенный в куче при помощи `new`, вы можете уничтожить при помощи `delete`. Если объект не выделен в куче, его удалить нельзя. Если объект выделен в куче при помощи `new[]` или `malloc`, его нужно освобождать при помощи `delete[]` или `free`.

---

Как правильно подсказывает @Harry, в пункте 2 для получения указателя вам нужно использовать `new`:

```
Proxy *p = new Proxy(*this, key);
```

Comment: разве в п.2 не ошибка компиляции т.к. левый и правый оперант оператора присваения имеют разные типы

Comment: @rikimaru2013: Именно так. У меня это есть в ответе.

Comment: У меня тогда вопрос, в 1 варианте, если у меня контейнер работает с таким кодом `int a=map[10]` то есть прокси ()  оператор имеется и возврашает инт. То когда этот экземпляр уничтожается? Просто я все еще пытаюсь решить проблему с [этим](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519093/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%83-map) вопросом

Comment: @Demolver: Для случая с `int` по сути то же. У вас на стеке создаётся `int` №1, копируется в `a`, и после этого функция заканчивается, и `int` №1 уничтожается вместе со всем стек-фреймом.

Comment: то есть фактически             `Proxy p(*this, key); return p;` && `return Proxy(*this, key);` равны и безопаснее чем указатель?

Comment: Гм, к п.2 - не `Proxy*p= new Proxy...`?

Comment: @Harry: Точно :)

Comment: @Demolver: Да, фактически это одно и то же. Но у вас при этом должен быть правильный конструктор копирования. Насчёт того, что безопаснее, ничего не могу сказать: у каждой из техник своё применение.

Comment: п.1. копирования скорее всего не будет из-за RVO. Даже если RVO не в силе, вместо копирования может быть перемещение (при наличии соответствующего конструктора). Обычно чтобы в таких случаях было явное копирование - компилятор надо об этом хорошо попросить.

Comment: @alexolut: Это да, в отсутствие копирующего конструктора возможны любые проблемы. А элиминация конструктора — оптимизация. Мне кажется, лучше думать в терминах копирования + as-if rule.

Comment: Хотя элиминация как раз ему и не подчиняется, да :)